# Issues when renaming WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

first of all, I am well aware that there are two other questions about the same topic I'm about to inquire, and I must sadly say that they haven't worked for me.

As it stands I am trying to create a simple WCF service which is to be consumed by a desktop application. I created it off the WCF Service Application that is offered through the New -> Project in Visual Studio 2013. That project has a template which has these two files: An interface called IService1.cs and the Service which is called Service1.svc.

Right out of the box this whole package works, but when I decide to rename those files with "IReservationService" and "ReservationService" respectively and put in my own code (which I can't find any mistakes in, not yet), when I decide to see if it's all working I get this bad boy:

[image: The refactoring(?) error.]

I regret to tell you that some parts of it are in Spanish, if you can't interpret them just yell at me and I will translate all of it for you.

This is the code involved:

**IReservationService.cs**

```
namespace WebService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IReservationService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<Business.Reservation> RequestReservationRetrieval();
    }
}
```

**ReservationService.svc**

```
namespace WebService
{
    public class ReservationService : IReservationService, IDisposable
    {
        ReservationRepository repo;

        public List<Business.Reservation> RequestReservationRetrieval()
        {
            //code goes here, skipped it so it doesn't clutter
        }

        private void ChangeSyncDate(DateTime date)
        {
            //code goes here, skipped it so it doesn't clutter
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            repo.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

As soon as I change the code in those two classes (IService1.cs and Service1.svc) which I assumed would have been refactored for mine to fit somewhat perfectly, that doesn't seem to be the case, and I get the error that is displayed in the image.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Real solution is to not use WCF. WCF Best Practice: Don't use WCF.

Comment: Amen. I can't believe it took me this long.

Comment: Real helpful comment there @Phill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was pretty much a refactoring nightmare, because the issue was somewhat hidden.

There's two files in ReservationService, or rather the Service that's to be consumed, in my case:

ReservationService.svc and ReservationService.svc.cs

ReservationService.svc contains just this tiny line:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WebService.Service1" CodeBehind="ReservationService.svc.cs" %>
```

And oh, surprise, there it is. Service="WebService.Service1" is exactly what was causing all these issues.

In order to get to ReservationService.svc, or whatever it's called on your Project you need to Right Click the .svc and click "View Markup".

This is an issue no one should ever have to deal with, I swear.

Comment: When you create one of these projects, there is a comment added above the service class that indicates what you do to rename the class.  There is a [Rename Refactoring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxxabwd.aspx) that you can use.

Comment: Oh, I used it about 5 times, but it didn't rename ServiceHost.

Comment: You also don't specify which version of 2013 you're running.  Do you have the latest update installed (Update 4)?  Any add-ons?  This is supposed to work, but then again, I always use ReSharper.

Comment: I updated it yesterday, I believe it's Update 4. As for addons, there's none. I'll look up ReSharper!

Comment: Ok, but you should also check the "Search in Strings" checkbox.  That's defaulted to off when you select Refactor.  When I did that, it worked for me just fine.

Comment: Alright, I'll make sure to check that the next time I do anything like this. Thank you so much for your input!